# HTML Canvas Background: W3C Schools Says It Works, Won't Work in Real Life

Tags: html, canvas

I'm trying to learn to use the canvas object in HTML and I've been using the resources at [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com) and found them quite helpful.

I am trying to create an image object and a canvas object, then draw the image on the canvas as background, then draw lines or polygons over the background image.  I have done this on the W3 Schools page successfully, but when I copy and paste that file into a local text editor, then save it on my iMac, and try to load it either in Chrome or Safari, the image can be seen by itself, but it cannot be seen as a background for the canvas.  So it works fine with their ["Try It Yourself!" editor](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_tut_img) (within Chrome), but not with the same source in an html file on my computer.

(Also, I did download the file "img_the_scream.jpg" and save it in my directory and it will load fine as an image by itself.  I plan, when I get this working, to use two canvases, each with its own background image and its own polygons and lines, so I have a '1' on the end of my variables for when I do that.)

Here's the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <p>Image to use:</p>
 <!-- <div style="display:none;"> -->
  <img id="pic1" src="img_the_scream.jpg" alt="The Scream" width="220" height="277">
  <br>
 <!-- </div> -->
 <p>Canvas:</p>
 <canvas id="can1" width="250" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
 Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
 <script>
  var c1 = document.getElementById("can1");
  var ctx1 = c1.getContext("2d");
  var img1 = document.getElementById("pic1");
  ctx1.drawImage(img1,10,10);
  ctx1.lineWidth   = 2;
  ctx1.strokeStyle = "green";
  ctx1.globalAlpha = .60;
  ctx1.beginPath();
  ctx1.moveTo(10,10);
  ctx1.lineTo(120,10);
  ctx1.lineTo(120,290);
  ctx1.lineTo(10,290);
  ctx1.closePath();
  ctx1.stroke();
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've read some references to a bug in Chrome with loading images or with drawImage, but from what I've seen, apparently that bug has been fixed.  (Also, this problem occurs with this HTML source in a local file on Chrome and Safari.)

Am I missing something basic or doing something sloppy?  Why will this work with the W3 School editor but not on my own computer?

Here it is on the W3 School Editor:

[image: Screenshot of W3 School editor]

And here it is, after I copied and pasted it into a local text editor, then saved it as a .html file and loaded it in Chrome (it looks the same on Safari):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experimented with this and Alohci's answer, in the comments, turned out to be correct.  When I tried the other answer (to include jQuery) to my page, it worked and I incorrectly assumed that was the correct answer.  What I actually needed was to be able to draw lines on maps, so I added this:

```
onload="doMaps()"
```

to my  HTML tag.  Then I added a routine:

```
    function doMaps() {
        doMap15('Hybrid15Canvas', 'Hybrid15Image')
        doMap15('RoadMap15Canvas', 'RoadMap15Image')
        doMap16('Hybrid16Canvas', 'Hybrid16Image')
        doMap16('RoadMap16Canvas', 'RoadMap16Image')
    }
```

and that loaded all four of my maps and drew the lines on them.  It worked perfectly and, even more, worked with all references to jQuery removed from my page.  That proves jQuery was not necessary and provided nothing other than loading time.

Since nobody else wrote up this answer, I thought it best to clarify for anyone dealing with this in the future.  The answer about jQuery may work (it did for me), it may not work.

Using an onload handler does work.